# jQuery Mobile showing all pages rather than 1st on startup when working with a multi-page template

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I have a single HTML file that contains three `div` elements in it,

Each `div` element has the attribute `data-role="page"` assigned to it.

When I load the HTML file, for some reason, it displays all of the `div` elements, rather than the 1st one only (I have another application I've written using HTML5&jQuery mobile and it works well and as expected - it only shows the 1st page when I load the HTML)

There are no significant differences between the two applications and I've been struggling with this for hours.

What might cause such a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the solution:

I accidently mistyped the file name for jQuery mobile's CSS file - so some classes were missing, classes that are used to hide non-active pages... along with other crucial classes

Comment: Please mark your own answer as correct. Then it gets filtered out of the list of questions needing answers. Thanks.

Comment: @Cymbals thanks for your comment, but as you might have (or not) realized, this is *not* my first day here... I can't accept my own answer, only after a 2 days time.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using 3G of wifi on the mobile? some service providers (O2 - UK) limit jQuery downloading on the device

Comment: all of the JS files are being deployed to the device, not using any external references

Comment: I understand this, in my tests jQuery does download but not fully, if you open your jQuery lib on the device and compare it with the same link on a desktop just make sure they are the same